# Does multiplying a regression variable by a random variable with mean 1 affect the estimates

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

I'm dealing with a regression of the form $\log(Z)=\alpha\log(X) + \beta\log(Y) + u$, but instead of observing $Z$, I observe $Z'=aZ$, where $a$ is a random variable with mean 1. Does using these observations affect the OLS estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Intuitively, I would think it wouldn't affect the values of the estimates but would affect the standard errors, but I'm unsure how to prove this mathematically.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are (i) observing $a(\alpha\log(X)+\beta\log(Y)+u)$ (which is literally what you wrote, but is a little strange insofar as it involves $au$) or (ii) observing $a(\alpha\log(X)+\beta\log(Y))$ or (iii) observing $a(\alpha\log(X)+\beta\log(Y)) + u$?

Comment: I'm recording triplets of variable $Z, X, Y$ and running the OLS model above. But instead of recording $Z$ accurately, I'm recording $aZ$. Do my regression estimates change from what they would have been if I recorded $Z$ correctly?

Comment: Thank you.  May we presume $a$ is positive?  Do you know the expectation of $\log(a)$?  After all, $\log(aZ)=\log(a)+\log(Z)$ shows you are observing $\log(Z)$ up to an *additive* error and that it's the mean of $\log a,$ rather than the mean of $a,$ that matters for OLS.